# Автоудаление части содержимого input

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно при вводе в текстовое поле `http://vk.com/id2` автоматически удалять `http://vk.com/`, оставляя в поле только то, что было напечатано после `http://vk.com/`.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слушать событие `oninput` на поле, и при каждом изменении проверять регулярным выражением, которое запомнит часть, которую нужно оставить:

```js
var i = document.getElementById('vk_link');
function checkField(e) {
  var m = e.target.value.match(/^(https?\:\/\/)?(m\.)?vk\.com\/(.+)$/);
  if( m) e.target.value = m[3];
}

i.addEventListener('input', checkField);
```

```html
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="vk_link">Профиль ВКонтакте</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vk_link" placeholder="ссылка на профиль ВК">
  </div>
</div>
```

В отличие от других ответов на данный момент, этот учитывает варианты из реальной практики:

```
http://vk.com/...
https://vk.com/...
vk.com/...
https://m.vk.com/...
```

Comment: Идеально! Спасибо!

Comment: Если что-то не совсем понятно, как работает – с удовольствием объясню.

Comment: достаточно того, что вы волшебный человек) Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

1. Добавляем `<input>`-у обработчик события потери фокуса.
2. В обработчике ищем необходимую строку в содержимом `<input>`-a.
3. Если необходимая строка присутствует в самом начале содержимого, то удаляем её из содержимого `<input>`-a.

С использованием jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
    var checkString = "http://vk.com/";
    var $input = $('#input');
    $input.on("blur", function() {
        var value = $input.val();
        var place = value.indexOf(checkString);
        if (place == 0) {
            value = value.substr(checkString.length);
            $input.val(value);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="input" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

То же самое без использования jQuery:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var checkString = "http://vk.com/";
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        var value = input.value;
        var place = value.indexOf(checkString);
        if (place == 0) {
            value = value.substr(checkString.length);
            input.value = value;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="input" />
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло!

Comment: а можно сделать так, чтобы исключался или http://vk.com или vk.com в зависимости от того как написал человек?

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее простой и элегантный вариант)

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?m?\.?vk\.com/, '');
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
```

Comment: не знаю, у меня не работает данный вариант.

Comment: что именно у вас не работает?

Comment: Не удаляет то что мне нужно.

Comment: При вставке из вашего вопроса http://vk.com/id2 - скрипт оставляет /id2 Можно убрать и слеш изменив регулярное выражение.

Comment: даже через кнопку "Выполнить код" ниже вашего ответа не работает. но не суть. Вопрос решен! Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то можно использовать атрибут placeholder

```
<input type="text" placeholder="http://vk.com/">
```

Comment: Не совсем так. Допустим человек в input написал "http://vk.com/id123" после того как фокус исчезает текст внутри input заменяется на "id123" или любой другой написанный после слеша.

Comment: @midagent без использования JavaScript-a такие фокусы не провернуть.

Comment: @Regent Как провернуть такой фокус с JS?